# Is it possible to consume a .Net WCF 4 Web Service by a non-.Net language?

Tags: .net, wcf

I've been beating my head against a problem for about a week and am now resorting to just a "is it even possible question".

Can other language connect to a web service that is written using .Net's WCF 4 framework?

When WCF first came out years ago (under .Net v3.0/winfx), I was able to connect a Java client to it using the basicHttpBindings; however, attempting to do the same thing under the latest and greatest version has me wondering if it's even possible.  I can create a WSDL from the Cassini web server that comes with Visual Studio but am always told that it's ill formed.  When I compare it to a WSDL from an ASMX service (which works), the two are vastly different.

Has anyone created a Web service with WCF 4 and been able to connect to it with a non-.Net language or even using something like WSDL.exe?

Comment: Yes, but I have observed that you need to flatten out the WSDL, before the non .NET language (java for example) can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can,  thats one of the selling points of SOA.  You interface via XML definitions, which transcends languages.

What type of contracts did you define?

Download [SOAP-UI](http://www.soapui.org/) and you can see for yourself.  A, its written in java, and B all it needs is the WSDL address.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll give it a shot and see.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow...nice tool. It works with the service I've had trouble with even though .Net doesn't.  Thanks for pointing out this tool.

Comment: What are the issues you are having with the service?